# What is a change of basis and how do i find it?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> W is a four dimensional vector space over a field F with basis S = (v1, v2, v3, v4). B is also a basis of W such that.
>
> $b1 =−v1, b2 =v1 +v2, \, b3 =−v1 −v2 −v3, \, and \, b4 =v1 +v2 +v3 −v_4.$

Then i'm asked to find the change of basis matrix P from S to B, so that,,,,,

$$ [x]_B  P[x]_S , \quad \text{for all x} $$

I'm not sure what a change of basis is how to find it

I'm thinking

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0 \\ -1&-1&-1&0\\ 1&1&1&-1   \end{bmatrix} $$

$$S = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1   \end{bmatrix} $$

Obviously i'm guessing but if this is through the matrix transforming B to S is simply the inverse.

Comment: A basis is a minimal set of vectors such that every other vector in the space can be written as a linear combination of them. "minimal" means that no subset of the basis will have the same property. It is not a matrix. The matrix you've labeled "B" is actually the matrix "P" you are after, except that you've made a sign error on one of the elements.

Comment: So i just gotta solve for $ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0 \\ -1&-1&-1&0\\ 1&1&1&-1   \end{bmatrix} = P\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1   \end{bmatrix} $?

Comment: What did I say about the matrix you labeled "B"? It was not "throw it and some other symbols together to make your life harder". And find and fix that sign error before going any farther.

Comment: Hey i fixed up up the thing matrix and got this vector $ = \begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0 \\ -1&-1&-1&0\\ 1&1&1&-1   \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1   \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1\\1\\-1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Excellent on finding the error. But you still haven't picked up that you are doing unnecessary work. That matrix is not B. B is not a matrix, the other matrix is not S. S is not a matrix. The products of those two matrices is another 4x4 matrix, not a vector, but that is immaterial, as you have no need to multiply them together in the first place. In my original comment, I told you what P was. You need to listen to that.

Answer (score 2):

If $v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 + \alpha_4 v_4$, then $v$ is represented in the basis $S=\{ v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \}$ as the column vector
$$
        [v]_{S} = \left[\begin{array}{c}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\\\alpha_4\end{array}\right]
$$
To write $v$ in terms of the basis $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$, figure out how to write all of the $v_j$ in terms of the $b_k's$:
\begin{align}
            v_1 & = -b_1 \\
            v_2 & = b_2-v_1 \\
                & = b_2+b_1 \\
            v_3 & = -b_3-v_1-v_2 \\
                & = -b_3+b_1-(b_1+b_2) \\
                & =-b_3-b_2 \\
            v_4 & = v_1+v_2+v_3+b_4 \\
                & = -b_1+(b_2+b_1)+(-b_3-b_2)+b_4 \\
                & = -b_3+b_4
\end{align}
In other words,
$$
        [v_1]_{B} = \left[\begin{array}{c}-1\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right],
        [v_2]_{B} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\1\\0\\0\end{array}\right],
        [v_3]_{B} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\-1\\-1\\0\end{array}\right],
        [v_4]_{B} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\-1\\1\end{array}\right]
$$
Therefore,
$$
          [v]_{B}= \left[\begin{array}{cccc}-1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right][v]_{S}
$$